# Is the set of periodic elements of a group a subgroup, if the commutator subgroup is periodic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ a multiplicative group such that the commutator subgroup of $G$ (the subgroup generated by the set of all commutators of $G$) is periodic.

I’m wondering if under the previous hypothesis, the set of the periodic elements of $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I denote the commutator subgroup of $G$ with $G’$, and the set of periodic elements of $G$ with $T$.

---

I tried to solve my doubt knowing that $G’$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, but I don’t know how I should continue.

Thanks in advance,

Antonino.

Comment: Is a periodic group a group with periodic cohomology? What is a periodic element?

Comment: An element $x$ of a group is said to be periodic when the subgroup generated by $x$ is a finite set. The order of $\langle x \rangle$ is called period of $x$. Consequentially  a group is periodic when each of its elements is periodic.  Sorry @doetoe but I don't know yet what is a cohomology.

Comment: Do you know  that the periodic elements of an abelian group always form a subgroup?  And that $G/G'$ is abelian?

Comment: I think "torsion" is the more standard term for what is called periodic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recall these three important statements.

1. If $H$ is an **abelian group** and $T_H$ is the subset of $H$ made of periodic elements, then $T_H$ is a subgroup of $H$.
2. For any group $H$, $1\in T_H$ and $x\in T_H\iff x^{-1}\in T_H$. Thus, to be $T_H$  a subgroup of $H$, we have to check only whether $T_H$ is closed under the multiplication of $H$.
3. Even if $G$ is not abelian, the quotient group $G/G'$ is abelian. Indeed, for any $x,y\in G$ we have $xy=yx[x,y]$, so $$xG'yG'=xyG'=yx[x,y]G'=yxG'=yG'xG'.$$ This implies that $T_{G/G'}$ is a subgroup of $G/G'$ because of 1).

Let now $x,y\in T_G$. Note that $xG'$ and $yG'$ are periodic elements of $G/G'$. We deduce from facts 1) and 3) that $(x G')(yG')=xyG'$ is also a periodic element. Thus there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $(xyG')^n=G'$, i.e. $(x y)^n\in G'$.

By the hypothesis, $G'$ is periodic, so there exists $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $[(x y)^{n}]^m=1$. We have proved that $xy$ is periodic, so $xy\in T_G$. Since $x,y\in T_G \Rightarrow xy\in T_G$, we conclude that $T_G$ is stable under the multiplication of $G$.

Comment: I have underestimated the statement number 1 and number 3.  

Many thanks, all is clear now!